# PHP: if statement not working inside foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have two arrays. One contains json-formatted objects with 2 variables each, so like array(3){["John"]=>string(2)"20" ["Mary"]=>string(2)"18" ["Paul"]=>string(2)"23"}. This shows people's names and their age. These ages are to be entered in the form on the browser and sent to the server using GET request. The other array contains objects of those people where the names are in common, but not their age. Each object has been created from a class and contains their name and their job. This array was created like this:

```
<?php
    class Person{
        private $name;
        private $job;
    }
    /*constructor*/
    public function __construct($name, $job){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->job = $job;
    }
    /*getters*/
    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function getOccupation(){
        return $this->job;
    }
    $john = new Person("John", "Police Officer");
    $mary = new Person("Mary", "Actress");
    $paul = new Person("Paul", "Professor");
    /* ... and more people */
    /*the second array contains all these data*/
    $people = array($john, $mary, $paul, /* more people */);
?>
```

As you can see, these arrays have name variable in common. What I want to do is, inside foreach which goes through the first array, check if the same name appears in the second array, and if it does, retrieve that person's job title. Assume that both of these arrays are a lot bigger than this and the order of data is different. I am not sure how to approach this. First I tried to check if the comparison itself works, but it does not work and I cannot figure it out why.

```
<?php
    foreach($_GET as $name => $age){
        echo $name;
        foreach($people as $person){
            if($person->getName() == $name){
                echo $person->getOccupation();
            }
        }
    }
 ?>
```

This prints nothing. Can anyone help me what is going on? Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
I am actually trying to achieve this inside HTML  tag.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Occupation</th>
  </tr>
  <?php foreach($_GET as $name => $quantity): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $name ?></td>
      <?php foreach($people as $person): ?>
        <?php if($person->getName() == $name): ?>
            <td><?php echo $person->getOccupation(); ?></td>
        <?php endif ?>
      <?php endforeach ?>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Comment: did you check what is return by  $person->getName() ?

Comment: Is all output is empty or just `$person->getOccupation()` doesn't give output ?

Comment: yes. $person->getName(), $person->getOccupation(), return the person's name and job title, respectively. So these getter functions are working correctly. Also echo $name prints the person's name correctly. But when compared,it does not go inside the if statement...

Comment: $person->getOccupation() is empty and it is not going inside if statement. I tried else statement to check, and everything went to the else section.

Comment: There must be some errors in your class constructor can you show us your code with omitted part in, please ?

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this...

```
<?php
$person=array(array('name'=>'aa','occupation'=>'xx'),array('name'=>'bb','occupation'=>'yy'),array('name'=>'cc','occupation'=>'zz')); //this is your array people
//print_r($person);
$name ='cc';//assume
foreach($person as $k=>$v)
{
    if($v['name'] == $name)
    {
        echo $v['occupation'];//outputs zz which is occupation of cc matched with $name
    }
}
?>
```

Not need to make function call..because values are already in array..so like this...

```
<?php

    foreach($_GET as $name => $age){
        echo $name;
        foreach($people as $person=>$value){
            if($value['name'] == $name)
            {
                echo $value['occupation'];
            }
        }
    }
 ?>
```